# Remove gaps in a stat_density2d ggplot chart without modifying XY limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run this code:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_density2d(data = Unit_J, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=..level.., alpha=0.9), lwd= 0.05, bins=50, col="blue", geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue",high="darkblue") +
  scale_alpha(range=c(0, 0.03), guide="none") + 
  xlim(-6600,-3800) + ylim(400,2500) + 
  coord_fixed(expand=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data = Unit_J, aes(x=X, y=Y), alpha=0.5, cex=0.4, col="darkblue") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I get this plot:
[image]

I know that increasing in this case X lims would solve the problem of unclosed lines shown on the left and right.

However, I want to keep these limits unchanged so that those "bugs" don't appear, and simply they must be beyond the limits, somehow hidden without creating those horrible lines.

Is there any possibility?

**EDIT (download data here):**

In order to ease and reproduce the example, you can [download the data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/140pSvkDnIc2Ro_MXjP1PIaJaO5tefZuT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-6600,-3300),ylim=(400,2500))` instead of using `xlim` and `ylim`.  This will plot the whole thing and then just show a window, rather than clipping the data before plotting.

Comment: It does not work @AndrewGustar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to expand the canvas using `xlim` and `ylim` so that there is enough room for `ggplot` to draw complete contours around the data.  Then you can use tighter `xlim` and `ylim` parameters within the `coord_fixed` term to show the window you want...

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_density2d(data = Unit_J, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=..level.., alpha=0.9), 
                                lwd= 0.05, bins=50, col="blue", geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue",high="darkblue") +
  scale_alpha(range=c(0, 0.03), guide="none") + 
  xlim(-7000,-3500) + ylim(400,2500) + #expanded in x direction
  coord_fixed(expand=FALSE,xlim=c(-6600,-3800),ylim=c(400,2500)) + #added parameters 
  geom_point(data = Unit_J, aes(x=X, y=Y), alpha=0.5, cex=0.4, col="darkblue") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]